# Counter and groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I want to analyse interval data. i have these columns:

```
Index(['index', 'Unnamed: 0', 'timestamp', 'heart_rate', 'speed', 'power',
       'distance', 'lap', 'cadence', 'step_length', 'altitude', 'start_time',
       'athlete', 'datum', 'weekday', 'run number', 'watage_HR',
       'power_cadence', 'cadence_HR', 'speed in km/h', 'pace', 'distance_km',
       'km', 'km_totaal', 'cardiac_drift', 'cardiac_drift_percentage',
       'duration training', 'avg_power_hr', 'diff_max_power_hr',
       'volume week duur', 'volume week interval', 'pace week duur',
       'pace week interval', 'week', 'jaar', 'km_binned',
       'roll average power/hf']
      dtype='object')
```

I want to count intervals based on power threshold, so I started with this code

```
df = df[(df["km_totaal"] == 20) & (df["power"] > 280)]
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])
df["diff"] = (df["timestamp"] - df["timestamp"].shift()).dt.total_seconds()
df = df[df["diff"] == 1].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Now I want to make a counter for the blocks based on timestamp and datum. So i want to count the number of interval blocks by date. So if timestamps connect it starts a count, till they don't connect then counter +=1, for a new datum (date) the counter needs to reset.

Outcome should be a column called 'interval_count' where the number of the interval on the specific date is counted. So i can easily plot the same interval for different days in one graph.

Comment: Could you show the expected result (I guess a dataframe) of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes dataframe where it simply has a column with a interval_count based on above mentioned requirements

Comment: You should provide a minimal input as example and the matching expected output.